# md-select not binding to the object referenced by ng-model

Tags: angularjs, angular-material

I have a form with some md-select dropdowns which im trying to bind with a scope object in my angular controller. 
The html looks like that :

```
            <div id="horizontal_form_category" class="row">
                <div class="col-md-2 col-lg-2" data-ng-repeat="r in categories[general]" dir="rtl">
                    <md-input-container>
                        <label> {{ r.name }} </label>
                        <md-select ng-model="formObject[r.name]" class="md-no-underline">
                            <md-option ng-repeat="option in r.values" ng-value="option "> {{ option }} </md-option>
                        </md-select>
                    </md-input-container>
                </div>
            </div>
```

The controller has a definition of the object `$scope.formObject = {};` (Although it should work without it)

But, unfortunately, the $scope.formObject object in my controller stays empty.
Any ideas what could cause such weird behavior ? I have some normal bootstrap components whom ng-model is written the same and are working just fine.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Does this help in any way? - [CodePen](https://codepen.io/camden-kid/pen/NRZqNj?editors=1010#0)

The **true** as the last parameter for $watch checks for changes in the object formObject.

Markup

```
<div ng-controller="AppCtrl" ng-cloak="" ng-app="MyApp">
  <md-input-container>
    <label> Options </label>
    <md-select ng-model="formObject['Options']" class="md-no-underline">
      <md-option ng-repeat="option in options" ng-value="option "> {{ option }} </md-option>
    </md-select>
  </md-input-container>
</div>
```

JS

```
angular.module('MyApp',['ngMaterial'])

.controller('AppCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.options = ["Earth", "Saturn", "Jupiter"];

  $scope.$watch("formObject", function () {
    console.log($scope.formObject);
  }, true)
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Apparently there wasnt any bug.
My form's md-select were empty and therefore the formObject was empty.
The minute I started puting values, the formObject got filled, one field at a time, containing only the fields that were set.
I added a default value and everything is now showing correctly, just to be sure this was the "bug".
In retrospect, this bevahiour actually saves me some lines of code so I adopted it :)
Gotta thank @camden_kid [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40318015/5958281) for the $watch tip, helped me figure it out in matter of seconds.